# how to set vs code's cmake options

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

How to set cmake's options on vscode? somebody said it is in task.json, the other said in setting.json, I test it works in setting.json
but there are still qutestions,

In setting.json, I set

```
  {
      //test ok 
     "cmake.configureArgs": [
         "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
         "-DENABLE_TENSORRT=on",
     ]
   }
```

But in the bottle of vscode on which cmake toolbar appears, it seems the program still build in Debug mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIqmm.png)

Comment: It's not `setting.jason` but `settings.json`. Now regarding build type, CMake Tools extension manages this value, so you just have to click on this value in the bottom taskbar and change to Release.

Comment: I made typo, and it has been corrected already, I did can click the taskbar to change its value.

Comment: This is not the recommended or expected way. If you are using the vscode cmake extension, there is a provided action to select a build configuration. If you are using kits, it is generated. If you are using CMake presets, then you have to define the build configurations. Kits are the default. You need to create a CMakePresets.json file to use presets.

Answer (score 0):

I personally set this at the root CMakeLists.txt by adding the following line

```
SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
```

after my cmake_minimum_required command. Now obviously this sets it to Debug but you can use any of the other (three if I am not mistaken) build types.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It is a way to set cmake's build behavior, but it don't explain how to set cmake's option correctly in vscode

Comment: It is preferrable to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` on the commandline instead of in a CMakeLists.txt file. Doing it in the file can take away the choice from the user of what configuration to use, which is usually not a desirable thing to do.